# PowerShell to create a directory within a junction point; or within a volume with no drive letter?

Tags: powershell, directory, hyper-v, windows-server-2016, windows-clustering

I'm working with Hyper-V and clustering in a Server 2016 environment. This is something I'm new to, and I'm trying to utilize some of my PowerShell experience to script the creation of a new folder within a shortcut (junction point, specifically), OR within a volume label that does not reflect an associated drive letter.

Under the directory **C:\ClusterStorage** there are shortcuts/junction points for the following: Volume1, Volume2, Volume3. I want to create a new child *directory* called "Hyper-V", within the **Volume1** *junction point*. However, when I try to run the below script, even though I'm designating **C:\ClusterStorage\Volume1.lnk** as the existing directory, and designating **\Hyper-V** as the new directory that I want to create as the *subdirectory*, the script tells me the Volume1.lnk already exists, as if it's trying to create the $rootpath anyway:

```
$rootpath = "C:\ClusterStorage\Volume1.lnk"
$newpath = "\Hyper-V"
New-Item -Path $rootpath -Value $newpath -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
```

So I'm not sure if there is a better approach to the above method I was trying (I cannot seem to find anything else). My other thought was to go directly to the source, if you will. Once the cluster is created properly, the **Volume1** junction point actually points to a volume named **Backups**. This volume has a drive letter assigned within Disk Management initially, but for whatever technical reason, once the cluster is fully-configured properly the drive letter is no longer associated with the volume.

I do not want to create a new drive letter for the **Backups** volume, for fear that it will tamper with the cluster configuration, so I was wondering if perhaps there's a means of using PowerShell to create the **Hyper-V** subdirectory within the volume named **Backups**. I can only seem to find topics on "Add-PartitionAccessPath" when I search for a means of doing this, and Add-PartitionAccessPath seems to assign a drive letter, which I don't want to do as I mentioned.

Is what I'm trying to accomplish here possible? It seems using **md hyper-v** within C:\ClusterStorage\Volume1 (using CMD Prompt) works exactly as I want, if that helps. I'm just looking to do the same in PowerShell syntax. Thanks so much!